Karate mock pending karate.proceed() blocking new request
I have set up a karate mock server with default proxy rule. And then I found a problem that if there is pending karate.proceed it will not running another incoming request until karate.proceed finish.
Is there any option to change this behavior?
Here are simple mock set up to reproduce. If I call /test1 follow by /test2 immediatly, /test2 will wait for 10s until /test1 finish before returning mock response.
Feature: test mock

  Scenario: pathMatches('/test1')
    # proxy to another service that will took 10s to response
    * karate.proceed('http://localhost:3000')

  Scenario: pathMatches('/test2')
    * def response = { message: 'hello' }

I have search through the github readme and not found anything about this.
I have tried running with --thread option but nothing changed.

Yes, we enforce a lock (look for the synchronized method) - which is not a great design. Ideally this should be configurable by the user - for example if you know the request is read-only. But this works well in most mocks, where the request is "hard-coded" or in-memory, etc.
My suggestion is please consider contributing code. We have an alternate way to do mocks that doesn't "lock" - but it lacks the proceed() that you want.
